# I was able to authenticate an existing user but I couldn't create new user account? Here is my Code

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

```
//*********************This was to authenticate user*********************

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {

      done(null, user);

});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {

       done(null, user);

});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {

     process.nextTick(function() {

        UserDetails.findOne({

          'username': username,

        }, function(err, user) {

              if (err) {

                  return done(err);

           }

            if (!user) {

              return done(null, false);

            }

            if (user.password != password) {

                 return done(null, false);

            }

            return done(null, user);

        });

      });

   }));

//*********************This was to create new user*********************

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {

     process.nextTick(function() {

        UserDetails.findOne({

          'username': username,

        }, function(err, user) {

              if (err) {

                  return done(err);

           }

              if (!user) {

                  var newUser = new UserDetails({"username":newUsername, "password":newPassword});

                   newUser.save(function (err, newUser) {
                        if (err) 
                        {
                            return console.error(err);
                        }
                        console.log("Document Saved!");
                   });
               return done(null, true);
            }

        });

      });

   }));
```

I have a `login.jade` file and `signup.jade`. So, when I want to sign in a user - if the user is in the database, it will authenticate the user successfully. But if the user does not exist it will insert a new user the database.

So my question is what should I change in code so that the a new user would be able to create account using the signup page and and an existing user would be able use login?

Thanks